# What is Yuuki's relation to Kaname?

Tags: vampire-knight

In Vampire Knight, the familial relationship between Yuuki and Kaname is relatively confusing. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 4):

Kaname is the founder of the Kuran family, and he was reawakened by Rido Kuran. After being reawakened, he was raised as the son of Haruka and Juri, who are Yuuki's parents. To summarize, Kaname is Yuuki's ancestor, though he was raised (after being reawakened) as her brother.

Yuuki was also born to be Kaname's wife, following the Kuran tradition of pureblood siblings intermarrying.

Cited from the Wikipedia article, which cites manga chapters.

Comment: should point out that Kaname was originally Haruka and Juri Son but Rido sacrificed him to awaken Lord Kaname. For Lord Kaname to suppress his blood lust from eons of slumber (and being woken in an incomplete state) and killing the Kuran Family he reverted to a child state.